# What should be done about abandoned questions that will likely never be answered?

Tags: discussion

Today *community* pushed [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/62819/33) up to the top of the queue. Unfortunately, the question will likely never be answered. Even if answers stated rolling in, the OP will likely never return to mark a correct answer or give any additional details.

This is just one example of questions like this, I'm sure there are a load more in the system.

What should be done with these questions?

<sub>***note:*** In this case, the OP has not been seen since Mar 29 '15</sub>

Comment: Don't you mean, what should be done about being [denied a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261326/new-reason-to-close-a-question-abandoned-question) that this site and many others so obviously need? Especially when they're not unclear and at the very least somewhat useful in the eyes of posterity? (please see my comments below)

Comment: It should be closed with OP feedback.

Answer (score 5):

The reason Community bumped the question ([for the 7th time](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/62819/timeline), no less) was that the answer got no feedback, positive or negative: it had 0 score. Now that the answer score is -1, the post won't be bumped again (per the [bumping rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511)).

Apart from the bumping issue, if the question lacks important details and the author is not around to provide them, it's reasonably to close the question as unclear (and in the longer term, delete it).

Comment: It seems to be positive again, but I agree: vote to close, insufficient information and no way to fix that.

Comment: What about questions [for example](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101458/goodman-gmp-100-4-red-light-blinks-4-times) that were answered in comments by the OP, or in an answer that they didn't mark as answered, that shouldn't necessarily be on their way to deletion because they might help somebody some day, but they're never likely to come back to themselves? Why can't we get a close reason due to inactivity of the OP? People with the same or similar problem should have *that* question closed as a dupe of theirs. 1-reps can't afford to place bounties on old questions...

Comment: Having to DV every new answer that comes along on that question doesn't sound like a good solution, and it's not a question that deserves DVs or deletion IMO, because it has a picture and an explanation of what 4 blinks *could* mean when that furnace has its connector unplugged. The community should have the option of marking a question "Solved" (through the discussion that ensued) but one that's more like a historical lock to prevent deletion, bumping, and more unnecessary answers.

Comment: @Mazura You don't have to downvote every new answer. Upvoting one of them is enough to stop bumping. If a question deserves to exist, that means some worthwhile answer can be given to it. It can even be a Community Wiki answer summarizing the comments, for example.

Comment: I suppose that's fine, as long as it only needs to have had an upvote and not a positive score. But doesn't that (in my example, OP's answer has +1/-1, thus zero) just prevent deletion and not bumping? Or did I just put it back in the bump queue? I'm guessing this is *by-design* to eliminate noise, but I'm kinda in the habit of retracting other people's one DV on "crappy answers" when I disagree that they're not useful, where I wouldn't UV it, if it didn't have a -1 on it. Which I'll admit is out of line but I don't think I'm the only one who does that.

Comment: @Mazura The link to bumping requirements is in my answer.